# Adding new column to relation in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 relations

```
R1 = ( a1,a2,a3...an)
R2 = (b1)
```

where R1 has lots of rows and R2 just has 1 row

Now I need an output which will have column added to R1

the equivalent SQL is

```
select a1,a2,a3...an,b1 from R1,R2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
A = load 'R1' as (a1, a2, a3, an);
B = load 'R2' as (b1);
C = foreach A generate a1.., B.b1;
DUMP C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If you are very clear with the value of that single field in R2 then you can use this.

Let say that if you know that value in that R2 file is 100 alone then

```
A = load 'R1' as (a1, a2, a3, an);
B = load 'R2' as (b1);
C = foreach A generate a1,a2,a3,an,'100' as newalias;
DUMP C;
```